Differentiate fetch errors between time out and page reload
I have the following code:
await fetch(url, payload)
    .then(raw => raw.json())
    .then(res => {
        response = res;
        console.log("response:", response);
        })
    .catch(err => {
        alert("An error occured");
        throw new Error(err);
    });

If there is no network connection, the catch statement is triggered, the console logs POST url net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED, then err is returned as TypeError: failed to fetch. This scenario is what I want so that I could notify users that there is a network error.
However, in another scenario where the network is either good or not, while fetch is ongoing and the browser's reload is pressed before the response, it will also trigger the same catch statement and err is also returned as TypeError: failed to fetch. This scenario is not what I want.
Is there a way to notify the error due to unreachable URL but not the error from reloading the page?

You could handle that base on the status code. If status code is 408 then it's a timeout error.

hi @kashaudhan. i edited my post for (hopefully) better clarification of what i need. thank you.

When reloading the page, the page is going to vanish momentarily anyway, isn't it? Is there really much of a point trying to handle this split second special case?
